# No account for team "TRRRRRRRRR"

Tags: ios, xcode, applepay

I am a developer of IOS and my role was defined as a developer. I want to add Apple Pay in my Xcode and add merchant Id but I got this error 
"No account for team "team number". Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials"
how can I solve it with the role of the developer in this team? Am I need any certificate or permission?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the instructions it gives you in the screenshot?

Comment: Give the guy a break - it's not a straightforward thing to know how to fix; see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't do it alone.

Someone with the right access level should doit.
They can do it from https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/ there they have capabilities options one of it is 
Apple Pay Payment Processing which should be enabled and configured.
After that is back to you.

Comment: the admin did it but I have that problem again

Comment: hmmm but is it shown in xcode what the admin did? I mean the ids in the xcode.